# How to access a struct array through a pointer?

Tags: go, struct

Following are my 2 structs

```
type Attempt struct {
    StartTime        string `json:"startTime"`
    EndTime          string `json:"endTime"`
    LastUpdated      string `json:"lastUpdated"`
    Duration         uint32 `json:"duration"`
    SparkUser        string `json:"sparkUser"`
    IsCompleted      bool   `json:"completed"`
    LastUpdatedEpoch int64  `json:"lastUpdatedEpoch"`
    StartTimeEpoch   int64  `json:"startTimeEpoch"`
    EndTimeEpoch     int64  `json:"EndTimeEpoch"`
}

type Apps struct {
    Id       string    `json:"id"`
    Name     string    `json:"name"`
    Attempts []Attempt `json:"attempts"`
}
```

The following test parses a json string into this `apps := &[]Apps{}`. When accessing the members of `apps`, I am getting the following error

```
invalid operation: apps[0] (type *[]Apps does not support indexing)
```

**The test**

```
func TestUnmarshalApps(t *testing.T) {
    appsJson := `[
      {
        "id": "app-20161229224238-0001",
        "name": "Spark shell",
        "attempts": [
          {
        "startTime": "2016-12-30T03:42:26.828GMT",
        "endTime": "2016-12-30T03:50:05.696GMT",
        "lastUpdated": "2016-12-30T03:50:05.719GMT",
        "duration": 458868,
        "sparkUser": "esha",
        "completed": true,
        "endTimeEpoch": 1483069805696,
        "lastUpdatedEpoch": 1483069805719,
        "startTimeEpoch": 1483069346828
          },
          {
        "startTime": "2016-12-30T03:42:26.828GMT",
        "endTime": "2016-12-30T03:50:05.696GMT",
        "lastUpdated": "2016-12-30T03:50:05.719GMT",
        "duration": 458868,
        "sparkUser": "esha",
        "completed": true,
        "endTimeEpoch": 1483069805696,
        "lastUpdatedEpoch": 1483069805719,
        "startTimeEpoch": 1483069346828
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "app-20161229222707-0000",
        "name": "Spark shell",
        "attempts": [
          {
        "startTime": "2016-12-30T03:26:50.679GMT",
        "endTime": "2016-12-30T03:38:35.882GMT",
        "lastUpdated": "2016-12-30T03:38:36.013GMT",
        "duration": 705203,
        "sparkUser": "esha",
        "completed": true,
        "endTimeEpoch": 1483069115882,
        "lastUpdatedEpoch": 1483069116013,
        "startTimeEpoch": 1483068410679
          }
        ]
      }
    ]`
    apps := &[]Apps{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(appsJson), apps)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    if len(*apps) != 2 {
        t.Fail()
    }

    if len(apps[0].Attempts) != 2 {
        t.Fail()
    }
}
```

How to access the fields Attempts, Id etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
apps := &[]Apps{}
```

`apps` has type `*[]Apps` (pointer to slice of Apps objects).

Are you sure you didn't mean to use the type `[]*Apps` (slice of pointers to Apps objects)?

Assuming `*[]Apps` really is the type you intended, you'd need to use `(*apps)[i]` to access every element of `apps`. That type is also the reason why you also need to use `len(*apps)` instead of `len(apps)` (and `*apps` for pretty much everything actually).

Comment: can i instead just do this: apps := []Apps{} ; err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(appsJson), &apps)

Comment: @AravindR.Yarram Sure, you can do that as long as your `Apps` type doesn't have any methods expecting pointer receivers (i.e. you don't have `func (a *Apps) Method(...)` ). Otherwise, you'll likely want to use `[]*Apps{}`.